# Socket Closed Error in Jaspersoft

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I uploaded a jrxml file to jaspersoft and tried to run it with some parameters. When more parameters is entered the report runs perfectly but not with less parameters and is showing an error as socket closed.

[image]

I think when the report has more data and it takes more time to run and thus socket closes. Is there any way i can either decrease the report runtime or increase the socket close time.

Comment: This situation isn't clear to me. What is "jaspersoft"? Where does the socket error come up? How does the report look like? How many parameters are we talking about?

Comment: Actually Jaspersoft generates reports like Crystal reports. For this report I created 13 parameters. If I provide values to more parameters, it will filter more and the report will come up quick. If I give just one mandatory parameter, the report generation takes lot of time. Then it comes:
Error Details 
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.
Error Message
Error filling report
Error Message
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : Report
Error Message
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Socket closed

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - I meant if you use the Jasperreport Server or what else you meant with "jaspersoft". If this is the server, please take a look into `tomcat/webapps/jasperserver[-pro]/WEB-INF/logs`. Then [edit] your question with the exception out of the log file. Does the statement work fine when you send it directly against the db?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket Closed iReport Clarity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225414/socket-closed-ireport-clarity)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but that will show the logs. I want to decrease the runtime of a report and increase the window so that the socket close occurs after a while. And the report is generated by the time.

Comment: As already stated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225414/how-can-i-solve-socket-closed-when-report-takes-long-time-to-run